# Slamdata: how to find cumulative sum based on the date

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, slamdata, nosql

i have used the query function in SlamData.
My code:

```
SELECT  
DATE_PART("year",thedate) AS year,DATE_PART("month",thedate) AS month,
SUM(runningPnL) AS PnL
FROM "/Mickey/testdb/sampledata3" AS c
```

`GROUP BY DATE_PART("year", thedate) ,DATE_PART("month", thedate)
order by DATE_PART("year", thedate) ,DATE_PART("month", thedate)`

The extract of my table:

```
PnL                 month      year  
-1651.8752           1         2001  
17180.4776           2         2001  
48207.54560000001    3         2001
```

Now, how can i find the cumulative sum of the PnL?
eg.`-1651.8752` for the first month
`15528.6024` for the second month
Thank you very much >.<

Answer (score 0):

I am generating sample data same as you for cumulative sum. Hope from this you get some idea.

```
Create table tempData 
 (
   pnl float,
   [month] int,
   [year] int
 )
 Go
 insert into tempData values ( -1651.8752, 1,2001)
 insert into tempData values ( 17180.4776, 2,2001)
 insert into tempData values ( 48207.54560000001, 3,2001)

 Select * , (SELECT SUM(Alias.pnl)
         FROM tempData As Alias
         WHERE Alias.[Month] <= tempData.[Month]
         ) As CumulativSUM
 FROm tempData
 ORDER BY tempData.[MOnth]
```

Comment: thank you very much.  As i am using SlamData and i am new to it, i have these errors when operating the code:  operator ';' expected; identifier table    .  how can i solve it? thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

done
my code is

```
SELECT a1.year, a1.month, a1.PnL, a1.PnL/(SUM(a2.PnL)+125000) as Running_Total
```

`FROM`/Mickey/testdb/sampledata6`as  a1,`/Mickey/testdb/sampledata6`as a2 
WHERE (a1.month > a2.month And a1.year=a2.year) or (a1.year>a2.year)
GROUP BY a1.year, a1.month,a1.PnL
ORDER BY a1.year,a1.month ASC;`